# Como listar cada Collation name com seu charset - Firebird 2.5

Tags: firebird

Quero fazer uma consulta envolvendo **RDB$Character_Sets**, **RDB$Collations** e **RDB$Fields** de forma a obter uma lista de "Fields" com os respectivos **RDB$Character_Set_Name** e **RDB$Collation_Name**.

Instrução SQL utilizada:

```
 select distinct
        Fields    .RDB$Field_Name        ,
        CharSets  .RDB$Character_Set_Name,
        Collations.RDB$Collation_Name
 from
        RDB$Character_Sets as CharSets  ,
        RDB$Collations     as Collations,
        RDB$Fields         as Fields
 where
     CharSets  .RDB$Character_Set_Id = Collations.RDB$Character_Set_Id and
     Fields    .RDB$Character_Set_Id = CharSets  .RDB$Character_Set_Id 
 order by
                        Fields    .RDB$Field_Name
```

Resultado obtido:

```
 RDB$Field_Name   RDB$Character_Set_Name   RDB$Collation_Name
 --------------   ----------------------   ------------------
 RDB$10           UTF8                     UCS_BASIC
 RDB$10           UTF8                     UNICODE
 RDB$10           UTF8                     UNICODE_CI
 RDB$10           UTF8                     UNICODE_CI_AI
 ...              ...                      ...
```

Ou seja, tem uma linha para cada RDB$Collation_Name. Como fazer para que cada RDB$Character_Set_Name, tenha o correspondente RDB$Collation_Name e somente ele,
reduzindo para uma única linha para cada RDB$Field_Name? Grato.

Comment: Uma forma eficaz seria utilizar o group by, mas nos testes que eu fiz aqui os resultados não foram satisfatórios.

Comment: Rapha, exponha visualmente como você deseja que seus resultados apareçam. O problema é que cada charset tem vários 'collations';

Comment: Olá Fabrício. Isso foi feito no corpo da questão: tem uma representação visual de como ñ quero que apareçam em "Resultado obtido". Embaixo tem um texto esclarecendo como quero q apareçam (cada Field_Name com seu respectivo e único Char_Set_Name e Collation_Name). Veja tbm a resposta que dei à questão. No meu teste deu certo.

Answer (score 1):

Após analisar melhor as tabelas `RDB$Character_Sets`, `RDB$Collations` e `RDB$Fields` constatei que a identificação unívoca entre o "Character Set" e o "Collation", se encontra na tabela "`RDB$Collations`", onde constam os campos "`RDB$Character_Set_Id`" e "`RDB$Collation_Id`". Por sua vez a tabela "`RDB$Fields`", tem também estas colunas, portanto, a cláusula "`Where`" tem que limitar por estas colunas associando "`RDB$Fields`" a "`RDB$Collations`" em RDB$Character_Set_Id e "`RDB$Collation_Id`". O "`RDB$Collation_Name`" é obtido da tabela "`RDB$Collations`" e o "`RDB$Character_Set_Name`" é obtido da tabela "`RDB$Character_Sets`" onde o "`RDB$Fields.RDB$Character_Set_Id`" = "`RDB$Character_Sets.RDB$Character_Set_Id`".

Assim, a cláusula "`Where`" fica:

```
CharSets.RDB$Character_Set_Id = Collations.RDB$Character_Set_Id and
Fields  .RDB$Character_Set_Id = Collations.RDB$Character_Set_Id and
Fields  .RDB$Collation_Id     = Collations.RDB$Collation_Id
```

Espero ter colaborado.